# How to convert two strings into an array of two in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking to extract keys and values from a hash. I manage to retrieve the data but in the wrong format. I am doing the following:

```
@message_count_series = @messages.collect { |p| "[#{p["created_at"]}, #{p["total_cnt"]}]" }
 => ["[2021-12-02 13:21:19.837233, 3]", "[2021-11-20 13:54:54.846048, 3]"]
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
 => [[2021-12-02 13:21:19.837233, 3], [2021-11-20 13:54:54.846048, 3]]
```

Just without the quote (not a string).

I tried the following :

```
@message_opened_series = @messages.collect { |p| ["#{p["created_at"]}, #{p["opened_cnt"]}"] }
 => [["2021-12-02 13:21:19.837233, 1"], ["2021-11-20 13:54:54.846048, 0"]]
```

Which takes me closer, but now my data are considered a string inside the array.

The following appear to work, but might not be very robust

```
@message_opened_series = @messages.collect { |p| [DateTime.parse("#{p["created_at"]}"), ("#{p["opened_cnt"]}").to_i] }
 => [[Thu, 02 Dec 2021 13:21:19 +0000, 1], [Sat, 20 Nov 2021 13:54:54 +0000, 0]]
```

Is there a better way to do this please ?

Comment: How does your original hash look like? What is the data type of the values in the original hash? Why do you think that your last version, that works, might not be robust? Is it possible that the hash contains invalid data?

Comment: Your desired result is not a legal Ruby object, therefore, you *cannot possibly* get this result.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
@message_opened_series =
  @messages.collect { |p| [p["created_at"].to_s, p["opened_cnt"]] }
 => [["2021-12-02 13:21:19.837233", 3], ["2021-11-20 13:54:54.846048", 3]]
```